# Enable PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED in Quarkus Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus, entitymanager

I'm currently migrating an existing application to Quarkus and I want to use [Quarkus Hibernate ORM](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm). The application was using Application Managed Entity Managers and now I have to switch to Container Managed Entity Managers with JTA by using `quarkus-hibernate-orm`. My code is relying on the fact that transactions are using the EXTENDED persistence context type, however, the default with `quarkus-hibernate-orm` is `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION` and I can't find how to change it.

AFAIK, usually one uses the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to change the `PersistenceContextType`, but that does not seem to work with quarkus when trying to inject an `EntityManager`. I'm currently using the quarkus specific `io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnit` annotation (as advised in the docs) but there does not seem to be a quarkus version of `PersistenceContext` (the non-quarkus `PersistenceContext` annotation does not work). Is it possible to enable the EXTENDED persistence context in Quarkus somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to enable the EXTENDED persistence context in Quarkus somehow?

Not at the moment. Entity managers in Quarkus are transaction-scoped, or request-scoped (and, I think, read-only) if used outside of transactions.

Feel free to open an issue to the [Quarkus project](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues) and explain your use case if you think this should be supported.